# How to mask the input while loading (before click)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpj1dvLa/) i tried to load. [ But it is not loading in jsfiddle, it works perfect in local ]

It is working only if i type in the textbox. How can i make the masking by default.

Here is the [demo](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin) by them

Here is the code i have so far.

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input id="name" type="text"></input>
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
    $("#name").mask("99/99/9999");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`document` should not be a string:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#name").mask("99/99/9999");
});
```

Comment: I removed the `quote` but still it is not loading by default

Comment: If you check the console, are there any errors appearing?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan actually it doesn't matter if document is a string or not.

Comment: The console was clean and no errors. Is the `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` issue ?